# ErrImagePull on EKS cluster core services

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to update my cluster and I am getting an error pulling the images.  This is happening on coredns, aws-node and other core services.  As far as I can tell I am a full admin on this particular cluster.  When I tried to do a docker pull to see if the issue was with something else, I am getting "no basic auth credentials".  I have done some research and cant see to find any references of this issue.

```
kube-system   coredns-bd9bb9b78-wwmdd                                  0/1     ErrImagePull            0          52m
kube-system   coredns-bd9bb9b78-wwmdd                                  0/1     ImagePullBackOff        0          52m
kube-system   aws-node-zgd2w                                           0/1     Init:ErrImagePull       0          62m
kube-system   aws-node-zgd2w                                           0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          63m
kube-system   coredns-bd9bb9b78-wwmdd                                  0/1     ErrImagePull            0          57m
kube-system   coredns-bd9bb9b78-wwmdd                                  0/1     ImagePullBackOff        0          57m
user@User-MacBook-Pro ~ % docker pull 643272868765.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/eks/coredns:v1.8.4
Error response from daemon: Head "https://643272868765.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/eks/coredns/manifests/v1.8.4": no basic auth credentials
```

Comment: To pull images from your ECR registry to your MacBook you have to install ECR credential helper: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper

Comment: Please paste the output of e.g. `kubectl describe pod coredns-bd9bb9b78-wwmdd` to get an detailed error message.

Comment: I have the ecr-helper already installed.  And on the describe, All I am getting is the `Back-off pulling image`  in the events.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a permissions issue.  I put the an ID that had permissions to download the image and it downloaded sucessfully.